# How to access Apple WatchKit WKInterfaceController list

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

In my watch extension code I am trying to prevent the display of a second interface controller in certain scenarios. My solution requires looking through the list of active view controllers.

Does anyone know how to get a list of all active interface controllers? You can do this in iOS using `self.navigationController.viewControllers` but I could find no navigation controller in WatchKit.

I have read through the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/) a number of times but they don't address this. Since you can push & pop interface controllers, there must be a list kept by the OS but I suspect there is no programming access to that list.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to work around it by making your own list, and save it in `NSUserDefaults` for example:

You should clear it on the init of your initial `ViewController`:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    // get user defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // empty the array at application launch
    [defaults setObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:@"activeVCs"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    return self;
}
```

And then in every other `ViewController`, you add and remove to this list on activate/deactivate of the controllers:

```
- (void)willActivate {
    // get list of VCs
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *listOfVCs = [defaults objectForKey:@"activeVCs"];
    [listOfVCs addObject:@"VC1"];

    // save array and sync
    [defaults setObject:listOfVCs forKey:@"activeVCs"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [super willActivate];
}

- (void)didDeactivate {

    // get list of VCs
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *listOfVCs = [defaults objectForKey:@"activeVCs"];

    // remove VC if exists
    if ([listOfVCs containsObject:@"VC1"]) 
        [listOfVCs removeObject:@"VC1"];

    // save array and sync
    [defaults setObject:listOfVCs forKey:@"activeVCs"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [super didDeactivate];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you can pass any valid context and access it in `awakeWithContext:`, I've used the technique of bundling a reference to the presenting view controller along with additional context in my WatchKit app. Not only does this allow you to build-up a list of presented interface controllers, but it also allows you to do things like assign delegates, inform controllers of interesting events, etc. I've published my `JBInterfaceController` project on GitHub: https://github.com/mikeswanson/JBInterfaceController